# How to dynamically Add rows into Table?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a Contact Form where the user can add 1 or more (max 5) contacts. Once the user clicks save, the program needs to check the number of contacts submitted and insert into the Contacts_Table accordingly as separate rows. For example, if the user provides 3 contacts, 3 rows should be inserted into the database. The problem here is am able to achieve the goal, but am trying to reduce the number of code lines.

Here is the sample code:

```
        string internalContact = "insert into InternalContact("
                                  + "Phone, FirstName, Surname)"
                                  + "values (@Phone, @FirstName, @Surname)";

        using (OleDbConnection conn1 = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(internalContact, conn1))
            {
                conn1.Open();
                cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                cmd1.Parameters.Add("FirstName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox34.Text;
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("Surname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox42.Text;                   
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("Phone", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox45.Text;

                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (TextBox64.Text != "")
                {
                    cmd1.Parameters.Clear();

                    cmd1.Parameters.Add("FirstName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox64.Text;
                    cmd1.Parameters.Add("Surname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox65.Text;                        
                    cmd1.Parameters.Add("Phone", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox69.Text;

                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                conn1.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: This approach does open you to security problems. You might want to look into using stored procedures. Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635149.aspx. Ignore the LightSwitch references. The article will show you how to create a Stored Procedure and call it from C#.

Comment: What RDBMS are you working with?

Comment: @Loki what security problems are you talking about?

Comment: I am using MS Access in the backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a struct list and pass all contact info to the method.

```
struct contactInfo
    {
        public string FirstName;
        public string Surname;
        public string Phone;
    }



private void insertContacts (List<contactInfo> pList)
{
using (OleDbConnection conn1 = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
    {            
            conn1.Open();

        foreach (contactInfo info in pList)
        {
           using (OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(internalContact, conn1))
            {

            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("FirstName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = info.FirstName;
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("Surname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = info.Surname;                  
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("Phone", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = info.Phone;

            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
             }

           }
            conn1.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. But how were you able to eliminate the use of TextBox34.Text above?

Comment: before calling this method you need to create struct list with using textboxes.   there is no pretty way to eliminate textbox id references..

Comment: Can I use a class instead of struct? Which is better?

Comment: If you just want to pass plain data I would recommend you to use Struct, It minimise syntax. But sure you can use class as well..